# NestJS: Case-insensitive search in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

Is there any way to do a case-insensitive search with NestJS in PostgreSQL?

I've succeeded in doing a case-sensitive search:

`let result = await myRepository.findOne({firstName: fName, lastName: lName});`

I'm trying to change it to a case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ILike` option should work for that:

```js
import {ILike} from "typeorm";

const loadedPosts = await connection.getRepository(Post).find({
    title: ILike("%out #%")
});
```

Example from https://typeorm.io/#/find-options/advanced-options

---

For `ILIKE` in Postgres see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.